# Merging two dataframes with irregular timestamp columns

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, timestamp, trading

I have a equity related data sample with prices that are date/time stamped at irregular, random intervals in the seconds, called `ESH5` and `ESM5`

I would like to generate another *full* data.frame, with a date/time column that increments the time by seconds, and fill in with the values from `ESH5`, `ESM5`. Any values will become the 'latest price' which will carry over to the next time interval unless a value exists for the matching time in `ESH5` or `ESM5`

For example, `ESH5`

```
    Date                 Price    Type
    22/10/2015 9:00:00   50.10    Bid
    22/10/2015 9:00:02   50.12    Ask
    22/10/2015 9:00:06   50.10    Trade
```

`ESM5`

```
    Date                 Price    Type
    22/10/2015 9:00:01   50.09    Bid
    22/10/2015 9:00:02   50.11    Ask
    22/10/2015 9:00:04   50.09    Trade
```

I am looking to generate a full data.frame like

```
    Date                 ESH5.Bid   ESH5.Ask   ESH5.Trade   ESM5.Bid   ESM5.Ask   ESM5.Trade
    22/10/2015 9:00:00      50.10         NA           NA        NA          NA          NA
    22/10/2015 9:00:01      50.10         NA           NA     50.09          NA          NA
    22/10/2015 9:00:02      50.10       50.12          NA     50.09       50.11          NA
    22/10/2015 9:00:03      50.10       50.12          NA     50.09       50.11          NA
    22/10/2015 9:00:04
    22/10/2015 9:00:05
    22/10/2015 9:00:06
```

Currently, I am generating the table with a for loop and if-else statements. I pregenerate `NA` empty data frame with the regular timestamp increments, the latest updated `bid`, `ask`, `trade`, then run a conditional check for the same time to fill the table.

My current code works, however the loop takes quite a while to process (10s of minutes). Are there any internal functions inbuilt in R I can use for this search and replace and carry over-like features?

Apologies if this is a bit hard to follow. Thank you.

Comment: It is not clear why you need to initiate with an empty data.frame.  Just create a data.frame with  `data.frame(vec)`, where `vec <-  seq(start_val, end_val, 1)`  If you can provide more details with some example, expected output, it would be helpful for others to comment

Comment: I have some data which are date time stamped at random second intervals. My finished result is to generate an complete array of values via a for loop , with a date column with 1 sec increments. I am using the `seq` command to generate this date column with `start`, `end`.

Comment: Please do update your post with the example data and expected result based on that

Comment: Have a doubt about the expected result. After the  `22/10/2015 9:00:03` row, the rows are all blank.  Does those values fill the rest of the rows as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do requires several steps:

First, create the date column with `seq`, as indicated bu @akrun

Secondly rebuild the structure of your data. This can be done in several ways, but i think the `dcast` function from the `reshape2` package is best:

```
ESH5c <- dcast(ESH5, Date ~ Type, value.var='Price')
ESM5c <- dcast(ESM5, Date ~ Type, value.var='Price')
```

And the last step is to `merge` these new data with your date vector.

Comment: Added! (wasn't needed in my case, but can't hurt). Probably depends on the order of the columns in the data frame. Strange however that it takes a column that has been specified as value. Not sure I should consider that a bug or a feature ;-)

Comment: order might be the key.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. The reshape command looks very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the 'Date' columns in both the datasets from 'character' class to 'POSIXct'.

```
ESH5$Date <- as.POSIXct(ESH5$Date, format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
ESM5$Date <- as.POSIXct(ESM5$Date, format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Get the 'min' and 'max' value by concatenating the 'Date' columns of these datasets.

```
MinD <- min(c(ESH5$Date, ESM5$Date))
MaxD <- max(c(ESH5$Date, ESM5$Date))
```

Create a sequence of datetime based on 'MinD', and 'MaxD' values as a new dataset

```
d1 <- data.frame(Date=seq(MinD, MaxD, by='sec'))
```

`merge` all the datasets by placing them in a 'list' and using `Reduce`

```
d2 <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by='Date', all=TRUE),
           list(d1, ESH5, ESM5))
```

Reshape the 'd2' dataset from 'wide' to 'long'

```
dLong <- reshape(d2, idvar='Date', varying=2:5, sep=".", direction='long')
dLong$time <- factor(dLong$time, labels=c('ESH5', 'ESM5'))
row.names(dLong) <- NULL
```

Change the 'long' format to 'wide' using `dcast`

```
library(reshape2) 
res <- dcast(dLong, Date~time+Type, value.var='Price')
```

Remove the extra NA columns

```
res1 <- res[!grepl('NA', names(res))]
```

Use `na.locf` from `zoo` to fill the NA values with the previous non-NA value

```
library(zoo)
res1[-1] <- lapply(res1[-1], na.locf, na.rm=FALSE)
res1
#                 Date ESH5_Ask ESH5_Bid ESH5_Trade ESM5_Ask ESM5_Bid ESM5_Trade
#1 2015-10-22 09:00:00       NA     50.1         NA       NA       NA         NA
#2 2015-10-22 09:00:01       NA     50.1         NA       NA    50.09         NA
#3 2015-10-22 09:00:02    50.12     50.1         NA    50.11    50.09         NA
#4 2015-10-22 09:00:03    50.12     50.1         NA    50.11    50.09         NA
#5 2015-10-22 09:00:04    50.12     50.1         NA    50.11    50.09      50.09
#6 2015-10-22 09:00:05    50.12     50.1         NA    50.11    50.09      50.09
#7 2015-10-22 09:00:06    50.12     50.1       50.1    50.11    50.09      50.09
```

Or using `dplyr/tidyr`, we can use `spread` to change the format of each datasets, `full_join`, them, along with 'd1', change the 'NA' values in each column with 'non-NA' previous value using `na.locf` and `mutate_each`.  Change the column names with `paste` (if needed).

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)
 library(zoo)

 res2 <-  full_join(spread(ESH5, Type, Price), 
                        spread(ESM5, Type, Price), by='Date') %>%
                    full_join(d1, ., by='Date') %>%
                    mutate_each(funs(na.locf(., na.rm=FALSE)), -Date) 

 names(res2)[-1] <- c(paste('ESH5', sort(ESH5$Type),sep="_"), 
                      paste('ESM5', sort(ESM5$Type), sep="_"))

  res2
  #               Date ESH5_Ask ESH5_Bid ESH5_Trade ESM5_Ask ESM5_Bid ESM5_Trade
  #1 2015-10-22 09:00:00       NA     50.1         NA       NA       NA         NA
  #2 2015-10-22 09:00:01       NA     50.1         NA       NA    50.09         NA
  #3 2015-10-22 09:00:02    50.12     50.1         NA    50.11    50.09         NA
  #4 2015-10-22 09:00:03    50.12     50.1         NA    50.11    50.09         NA
  #5 2015-10-22 09:00:04    50.12     50.1         NA    50.11    50.09      50.09
  #6 2015-10-22 09:00:05    50.12     50.1         NA    50.11    50.09      50.09
  #7 2015-10-22 09:00:06    50.12     50.1       50.1    50.11    50.09      50.09
```